# forEach Function doesn't match documentation

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am following along with this documentation:

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/foreach.html

Basically when I copy the example like this:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://FIREBASEID.firebaseio.com/users");
ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  // The callback function will get called twice, once for "fred" and once for "barney"

  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

    // key will be "fred" the first time and "barney" the second time
    var key = childSnapshot.key();
    console.log(key);

  });
});
```

Unlike the example where you would expect to get

```
> Fred
> Barney
```

I instead get

```
> First
> Last
> First
> Last
```

Which is the keys inside each of the names above.

I can fix it by changing the firebase ref to this:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://FIREBASEID.firebaseio.com/");
```

Why isn't this working like the documentation?

Comment: The example gives you `fred` not `Fred` - an important distinction.

Comment: What you've described is working as expected. You're not following the example closely which explains the difference in outcome.

Comment: Hey Dylan. Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for trying Firebase. As you might have noticed, you're getting some negative feedback. To prevent this, it typically helps if you give us the exact data and code you're using. You can get the data from your Firebase dashboard by clicking the Export button. And also make sure that you show the code you actually use. Don't type different code for the question. Instead [reproduce your problem in a minimum set of data + code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and share those.

Comment: Most likely your value of `ref` is pointing to a specific user. That means that `snapshot.forEach()` is looping over the properties of that user, instead of over the users in a set.

Answer (score 2):

The docs also provide a data structure:

```
{
  "users": {
    "fred": {
      "first": "Fred",
      "last": "Flintstone"
    },
    "barney": {
      "first": "Barney",
      "last": "Rubble"
    }
  }
}
```

**You have not provided the data structure you are working with**. The answer is that the data structure you have created is not what you actually intended it to be. It could be something similar to this:

```
{
  "users":[{
   "First": "Fed",
   "Last": "Flintstone"
 },
 {
   "First": "Barney",
   "Last": "Rubble"
 }]
}
```

when you probably meant it to be:

```
{
 "users":{
   "Fred": {
      "First": "Fred",
      "Last": "Flintstone"
   },
   "Barney": {
      "First": "Barney",
      "Last": "Rubble"
   },
  }
}
```